# The extract_links() function in scrapy isn't returning the correct return links from the response

Tags: python, scrapy, screen-scraping

I'm trying to use scrapy to get links from a query entered by the user. The code I have till now is this:

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class GoogleCrawler(Spider):
    name = 'googlecrawler'
    start_urls = ["https://www.google.com/search?q="]

    def __init__(self, toFind):
        self.toFind = toFind

    def parse(self, response):
        linkEx = LinkExtractor()
        self.toFind = self.toFind.split(" ")
        googleLink = self.start_urls[0]

        for word in self.toFind[:-1]:
            googleLink += f"{word}+"
        googleLink += f"{self.toFind[-1]}"

        response = response.replace(url = googleLink)
        self.start_urls[0] = googleLink
        print(f"\n\n{response}\n\n")
        for link in linkEx.extract_links(response):
            print(link)


process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(GoogleCrawler, "adding parameters to parse function in scrapy")
process.start()
```

In the second last line I add a query, and in the parse function I break it down and make a google search url. I've seen the url printed and confirmed that the *googleLink* variable is legit.
I've come to find that giving the *googleLink* as an argument to *extract_links()* doesn't work, because it wants a response. So I've tried to change the url of the response variable and even the *start_urls* value, but the results I get from that final for loop is nothing related to my search. I get the links for google setting preferences and links to google images, maps, drives, etc.

What can I do to get the results that I want?

Comment: You don't make any requests with your search parameters. `start_urls` is only used when you begin the spider, so assigning to it isn't going to do anything. Have you worked through the [scrapy tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html)? That shows how you could define a `start_requests` method

Comment: @tomjn Thanks, I'll go through the tutorial again. Changing the ```start_urls``` might not do anything, but the link extractor still doesn't give me the right links when I give ```response``` as a parameter. Any idea about that?

Comment: [`Response.replace`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.replace) just replaces the attributes of the response, you aren't making a new request. So you just have the results of your original request to "https://www.google.com/search?q=" (basically the google home page)

Comment: @tomjn So how do I fix this? Do I have to change the request / make a new request now?

Comment: You will have to yield a new `Request`, or why not write a `start_requests` method as in the tutorial to do the initial search and then you can parse that in your normal parse method.